# How can I isolate live Wolbachia endosymbionts from Drosophila

Tags: cell-biology, zoology, microbiology, entomology

I am interested to culture Wolbachia bacteria in cell line.

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! Could your add some details on what kinds of approaches you are thinking? Perhaps some more info on characteristics of Wilbachia?

Comment: If I had to close then I would vote to close this as homework because a simple google search fetches relevant answers. I am not voting to close, however, because Wolbachia is not such a common topic. -1 for lack of effort

Answer (score 1):

You can see [this](http://www.nature.com/protocolexchange/protocols/15#/main) protocol for *Wolbachia* isolation:

See [this](http://ci.nii.ac.jp/els/110007004674.pdf?id=ART0008920957&type=pdf&lang=en&host=cinii&order_no=&ppv_type=0&lang_sw=&no=1422947612&cp=) protocol for infecting cell lines with *Wolbachia*.

In [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9013253) study the authors have established a cell line from a *Wolbachia* infected tissue of *Aedes albopictus*. You can have a look at that too.

Comment: Why downvote ??

Comment: I downvoted because I thought it to be somewhat of a link-only answer. Removed. If you add some details I am totally happy to upvote, but likely the question needs work before a proper answer is possible.

Comment: @ChrisStronks Cannot paste the protocol here. Since the OP is asking only for the protocol, I provided the link (all links are to published articles and are not likely to be broken in future). To add anything more, the question needs to be refined

Comment: Agreed, totally. Again, after question refinement I am happy to upvote.